# Zookeeper 3.6.0 TCP requirements changed?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

After upgrading 1 of the existing v3.5.7 servers too V3.6.0 I found that the new node would not join the existing Zookeeper cluster, instead it would enter an endless loop of the following.

Logs on the Existing node in cluster reported

```
 [myid:1] - WARN  [QuorumPeer[myid=1](plain=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0]:2181).    (secure=disabled):QuorumCnxManager@685] - Cannot open channel to 3 at election address service-    zk-x.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx/172.26.47.92:3888
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
    at      org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectOne(QuorumCnxManager.java:656)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectOne(QuorumCnxManager.java:720)
    at     org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectAll(QuorumCnxManager.java:741)
    at     org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection.lookForLeader(FastLeaderElection.java:910)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.run(QuorumPeer.java:1229)
```

Running a tcpdump on an existing node the following

```
IP 172.26.47.18.7 > 172.26.47.92.36638: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 3465718752, win 0, length 0
```

.92 is the new server (V3.6.0)

After enabling port 7 on the firewall the cluster election was successful and the new server joined the cluster as normal.   I might have missed this in the release notes for v3.6.  Can anyone confirm this change?

Answer (score 0):

If you still wonder what has changed in the new ZK version 3.6.0 that requires this port. This is the new parameter (multiAddress.reachabilityCheckEnabled) that is set to true by default and requires port 7 (echo) to be opened. Either open this port or set this flag to false however it is not recommended in production to change its default flag as explained in the documentation: https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.6.0/zookeeperAdmin.html
This flag (port) is only required when you set multiAddress.enabled=true to specify multiple addresses for each ZooKeeper server instance. Cheers!